# How to responsively calculate line width relative to an absolute position image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that is absolutely positioned to bleed outside the edge of the container. Then I have 3 descriptions of this image that are relatively positioned within the main page container. I now need to add callout lines to point to specific spots on the image. I'm haivng trouble getting them to line up.

See my [codepen](https://codepen.io/lsterling03/pen/bGqZgBq).

I thought I could just make the line width a percentage and it would adjust responsively with the image. But that's not happening. I've tried using `vw` but that also doesn't work. Is it possible to do this with CSS? Or do I need javascript? I'n open to whatever works best. I just can't seem to figure out the correct calculation.

The framework of the main container has to remain, but I can adjust the markup of everything inside the `.wheel` div if needed. Thanks for your time!

(Edit: I don't need it to work on mobile -- I'm going to stack it and remove the lines for small screens.)

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused by the two containers versus 'page' as you have put in a comment talking of *the* container but there are two and you say the image bleeds off the page - so what is the significance of the outer container?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that absolute positioning is the best option for this use case. For example, opening this on one of my larger monitors made the circular image move towards the center of the browser.

Comment: @AHaworth The outer container keeps all the content in line. It's a long page with lots of other content (Wordpress template). This one section with the wheel needs to break out of the layout, but the container has to stay.

Comment: @FrankFiumara It's okay if the wheel no longer bleeds on super large monitors. I think it will bleed for the majority of users. There's a point where it would get too far from the main content, so I need it to stay in relation to that, more than the edge of the page. My issue is getting those lines to hit the right part of the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my own question. Turns out the problem was simple. I just needed to move the image inside the same container as the content, so they had the same relative parent. Positioning 101. Thanks to @FrankFiumara for mentioning that the image did not bleed on a much larger monitor -- that's what made me realize it didn't actually need to be bleed off the page. It just needed to bleed outside of the content container.

Here's my revised [codepen](https://codepen.io/lsterling03/pen/bGqZqmz).

I changed this:

```
  <div class="wheel-image">
    <img />
  </div>

  <div id="content-container" class="container">
    <div class="wheel-content">
    </div>
 </div>
```

to this:

```
  <div id="content-container" class="container">
  
    <div class="wheel-image">
      <img />
    </div>

    <div class="wheel-content">
    </div>
 </div>
```